# Тестирование контроллера Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit, mockito

При тестировании контроллера выполняется три метода. add, getSum и remove. Выполняться они должны в такой же очередности. Первые два проходят удачно. А вот удалить сущности из БД не получается, т.к. spring их не находит. В чем может быть проблема?

P.S. если отдельно вызвать первые два, а потом третий, то тест пройдет.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class NumberControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private NumberController numberController;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(numberController).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void addNumber() throws Exception {
        numberController = mock(NumberController.class);

        MvcResult result = this.mockMvc.perform(post("/api/add?name=test1&value=2").accept(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/json;charset=UTF-8")))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().contentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8"))
                .andReturn();

        String res = result.getResponse().getContentAsString();
        assertEquals(res, "{\"code\":0,\"description\":\"OK\"}");

        result = this.mockMvc.perform(post("/api/add?name=test2&value=2").accept(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/json;charset=UTF-8")))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().contentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8"))
                .andReturn();

        res = result.getResponse().getContentAsString();
        assertEquals(res, "{\"code\":0,\"description\":\"OK\"}");
    }

    @Test
    public void getSumNumber() throws Exception {
        numberController = mock(NumberController.class);

        MvcResult result = this.mockMvc.perform(post("/api/sum?name1=test1&name2=test2").accept(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/json")))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().contentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8"))
                .andReturn();

        String res = result.getResponse().getContentAsString();
        System.out.println(res);
        assertEquals(res, "{\"sum\":4,\"code\":0,\"description\":\"OK\"}");
    }

    @Test
    public void removeNumber() throws Exception {
        numberController = mock(NumberController.class);

        MvcResult result = this.mockMvc.perform(post("/api/remove?name=test1").accept(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/json;charset=UTF-8")))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().contentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8"))
                .andReturn();

        String res = result.getResponse().getContentAsString();
        assertEquals(res, "{\"code\":0,\"description\":\"OK\"}");

        result = this.mockMvc.perform(post("/api/remove?name=test2").accept(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/json;charset=UTF-8")))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().contentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8"))
                .andReturn();

        res = result.getResponse().getContentAsString();
        assertEquals(res, "{\"code\":0,\"description\":\"OK\"}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Уберите "@Before", добавьте аннотацию "@AutoconfigureMockMvc" в класс. Сделайте "@Autowired" над mockmvc и все заработает. Ах да, "SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.MOCK" не забудьте.

Comment: У вас сейчас все перемешалось. Интегрейшин тест в котором поднимается все приложение(включая встроенный хттп сервер на реальном порту) и мок мвц, который отдельно в этом же тесте настраивается.

Comment: @aleshka-batman , благодарю, все заработало.)
Т.е. я позволяю спрингу самому сбилдить mockMvc?
WebEnvironment.MOCK позволяет поднять сервер не на релальном порту?)
Можно пожалуйста подробнее?

Comment: Дело в том, что поднимать все приложение вместе с реальным хттп сервером слишком! затратно для теста. Такие тесты чаще всего используются в E2E.  WebEnvironment.MOCK - поднимает весь ваш контекст, включая контроллеры, настраивает мок мвц, но не поднимает сервер.

Comment: @aleshka-batman , а есть ли какие-то особенности при тестировании с помощью H2? Прогнал тесты на MySQL, все завелось отлично. А при использовании H2, не находит сущности в БД.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/906298/org-h2-jdbc-jdbcsqlexception-schema-information-schema-not-found/906391#906391